# S3 Bucket PutObject blocks main thread

Tags: android, amazon-s3, kotlin

I am uploading an image to S3 bucket.It works, but while uploading, it blocks the main thread (the UI essentially stops during download). I had to use an async task to get the upload to work, because if I do not, Android throws exception about network calls on main thread. How do I force upload to run on background thread?

Here is my code:

```
 val metaData = ObjectMetadata()
        metaData.setContentLength(myBitmapByteArray.size.toLong())

          doAsync {
                try {
                    s3Client.putObject("my-bucket", "my_test_file/abc.bmp", myByteInputStream, metaData)
                } catch (e: AmazonServiceException) {
                    System.err.println(e.errorMessage)
                    System.exit(1)
                }
                Log.i("AMAZON", "File upload to s3 completed")
                //TODO: uithread never called below
    //            uiThread {
    //
    //            }
            }
```